concate column rows with previous rows based on a condition
I have this CSV file, (part of a very large one)



Course/Section
Credits
Course Name
Time
Building
Instructor
Exam Date
Course Language




ACCT1112/10
3
Introductory Financial
MON
CMT/E07
xxxxxxx
8/5/2022
English




Accounting
08:00-09:50


SUN









08:00-11:00









E15



ACCT1112/11
3
Introductory Financial
WED
CMT/E07
xxxxxxx

English




Accounting
08:00-09:50






ACCT1112/20
3
Introductory Financial
MON
CMT/E05
xxxxxxx
8/5/2022
English




Accounting
10:00-11:50


SUN









08:00-11:00









E16



ACCT1112/21
3
Introductory Financial
WED
CMT/E05
xxxxxxx

English




Accounting
10:00-11:50






ACCT1112/30
3
Introductory Financial
MON
CMT/E06
xxxxxxx
8/5/2022
English




Accounting
12:00-13:50


SUN









08:00-11:00









E17



ACCT1112/31
3
Introductory Financial
WED
CMT/E06
xxxxxxx

English




Accounting
12:00-13:50






ACCT1112/40
3
Introductory Financial
MON
CMT/E23
xxxxxxx
8/5/2022
English




Accounting
14:15-16:05


SUN









08:00-11:00









E18



ACCT1112/41
3
Introductory Financial
WED
CMT/E23
xxxxxxx

English




Accounting
14:15-16:05






ACCT1112/50
3
Introductory Financial
SUN
CMT/E27
xxxxxxx
8/5/2022
English




Accounting
10:00-11:50


SUN









08:00-11:00









E19



ACCT1112/51
3
Introductory Financial
THU
CMT/E27
xxxxxxx

English




Accounting
10:00-11:50






ACCT1112/60
3
Introductory Financial
TUE
CMT/E16
xxxxxxx-1
8/5/2022
English




Accounting
10:00-11:50

xxxxxxx-2
SUN









08:00-11:00









E20



ACCT1112/61
3
Introductory Financial
THU
CMT/E16
mmmmm-1

English




Accounting
08:00-09:50

mmmmm-2





I want to convert it to



Course/Section
Credits
Course Name
Time
Building
Instructor
Exam Date
Course Language




ACCT1112/10
3
Introductory Financial Accounting
MON 08:00-09:50
CMT/E07
xxxxxxx
8/5/2022 SUN 08:00-11:00 E15
English


ACCT1112/11
3
Introductory Financial Accounting
WED 08:00-09:50
CMT/E07
xxxxxxx

English


ACCT1112/20
3
Introductory Financial Accounting
MON 10:00-11:50
CMT/E05
xxxxxxx
8/5/2022 SUN 08:00-11:00 E16
English


ACCT1112/21
3
Introductory Financial Accounting
WED 10:00-11:50
CMT/E05
xxxxxxx

English


ACCT1112/30
3
Introductory Financial Accounting
MON 12:00-13:50
CMT/E06
xxxxxxx
8/5/2022 SUN 08:00-11:00 E17
English


ACCT1112/31
3
Introductory Financial Accounting
WED 12:00-13:50
CMT/E06
xxxxxxx

English


ACCT1112/40
3
Introductory Financial Accounting
MON 14:15-16:05
CMT/E23
xxxxxxx
8/5/2022 SUN 08:00-11:00 E18
English


ACCT1112/41
3
Introductory Financial Accounting
WED 14:15-16:05
CMT/E23
xxxxxxx

English


ACCT1112/50
3
Introductory Financial Accounting
SUN 10:00-11:50
CMT/E27
xxxxxxx
8/5/2022 SUN 08:00-11:00 E19
English


ACCT1112/51
3
Introductory Financial Accounting
THU 10:00-11:50
CMT/E27
xxxxxxx

English


ACCT1112/60
3
Introductory Financial Accounting
TUE 10:00-11:50
CMT/E16
xxxxxxx-1 xxxxxxx-2
8/5/2022 SUN 08:00-11:00 E20
English


ACCT1112/61
3
Introductory Financial Accounting
THU 08:00-09:50
CMT/E16
mmmmm-1 mmmmm-2

English



I tried
for i in range(len(df) - 1, 0, -1):
    if pd.isna(df.loc[i, 'Course/Section']):
        for col in df.columns:
            if pd.notna(df.loc[i, col]):
                df.loc[i - 1, col] = f"{df.loc[i - 1, col]} {df.loc[i, col]}" if pd.notna(df.loc[i - 1, col]) else df.loc[i, col]


df = df.dropna(subset=['Course/Section']).reset_index(drop=True)

But my code does not seem to work as intended.
So, I want to concatenate row values with previous one, one by one from bottom to top as long the column Course/Section is empty until I reach the row where Course/Section is not empty

Create groups based on existing values in column 'Course/Section' with cumsum, then groupby and aggregate joining the values in each group:
g = df["Course/Section"].notna().cumsum()
df = (
    df.fillna("")
    .groupby(g, as_index=False)
    .agg(lambda x: " ".join(x.astype(str)).strip())
)

   Course/Section Credits                        Course Name             Time Building           Instructor                     Exam Date Course Language
0     ACCT1112/10     3.0  Introductory Financial Accounting  MON 08:00-09:50  CMT/E07              xxxxxxx  8/5/2022 SUN 08:00-11:00 E15         English
1     ACCT1112/11     3.0  Introductory Financial Accounting  WED 08:00-09:50  CMT/E07              xxxxxxx                                       English
2     ACCT1112/20     3.0  Introductory Financial Accounting  MON 10:00-11:50  CMT/E05              xxxxxxx  8/5/2022 SUN 08:00-11:00 E16         English
3     ACCT1112/21     3.0  Introductory Financial Accounting  WED 10:00-11:50  CMT/E05              xxxxxxx                                       English
4     ACCT1112/30     3.0  Introductory Financial Accounting  MON 12:00-13:50  CMT/E06              xxxxxxx  8/5/2022 SUN 08:00-11:00 E17         English
5     ACCT1112/31     3.0  Introductory Financial Accounting  WED 12:00-13:50  CMT/E06              xxxxxxx                                       English
6     ACCT1112/40     3.0  Introductory Financial Accounting  MON 14:15-16:05  CMT/E23              xxxxxxx  8/5/2022 SUN 08:00-11:00 E18         English
7     ACCT1112/41     3.0  Introductory Financial Accounting  WED 14:15-16:05  CMT/E23              xxxxxxx                                       English
8     ACCT1112/50     3.0  Introductory Financial Accounting  SUN 10:00-11:50  CMT/E27              xxxxxxx  8/5/2022 SUN 08:00-11:00 E19         English
9     ACCT1112/51     3.0  Introductory Financial Accounting  THU 10:00-11:50  CMT/E27              xxxxxxx                                       English
10    ACCT1112/60     3.0  Introductory Financial Accounting  TUE 10:00-11:50  CMT/E16  xxxxxxx-1 xxxxxxx-2  8/5/2022 SUN 08:00-11:00 E20         English
11    ACCT1112/61     3.0  Introductory Financial Accounting  THU 08:00-09:50  CMT/E16      mmmmm-1 mmmmm-2                                       English

